# UNICODE bidirectional text characters

Tags: unicode, special-characters

need to work with malware which uses bidi strings. They not so widely documented and I've found part of them in one place, part in another. For now I have these:

```
 1. LRM - 0x200E
 2. RLM - 0x200F
 3. LRE - 0x202A
 4. RLE - 0x202B
 5. PDF - 0x202C
 6. LRO - 0x202D
 7. RLO - 0x202E
```

I want to ask if it is all UNICODE special characters, or I missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are Unicode characters related to directionality. They are used to control writing direction; they are invisible control characters, i.e. they are not displayed graphically, but they may affect the way printable characters are presented (left-to-right vs. right-to-left writing direction). Their effects are normatively defined in Unicode Standard Annex #9,
[Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/).

Generally, to find information about specific characters by their Unicode number (code point), [Unicode Character Search](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm) at Fileformat.info is a good starting point.